# How to force org-attach to create lowercase UUIDs

Tags: org-mode

When using the org-attach function on macOS the IDs are that are created are uppercase. It is possible to change the folder name to lowercase via `(advice-add #'org-attach-id-uuid-folder-format :filter-return #'downcase)` but the format in the ID property remains uppercase.

Example:

org attachment relative location (after adding the above advice): `data/3e/8bb725-3fb7-4f3f-80b2-baa4369a48ce/example.pdf`

snippet from org file:

```
** Example                                                             :ATTACH:
   :PROPERTIES:
   :ID:       3E8BB725-3FB7-4F3F-80B2-BAA4369A48CE
   :End:
```

On macOS I can still open the attachment because of filesystem case-insensitivity. However on Linux if you try to open the attachment, no corresponding ID can be found. I would like all org-attach IDs to be lowercase in both the folder name and its reference. How can I accomplish this?

Edit: uuidgen is used on macOS and Linux for me, and `org-id-new`/ `org-id-get-create`/`uuidgen` always returns an uppercase ID on macOS and lowercase ID on Linux.

Comment: In my (Fedora 33 linux) system, ID's are lower case. You need to figure out what method you are using to generate IDs and go from there. Start by evaluating `(org-id-new)` in your `*scratch*` buffer and seeing what it gives you. It's likely that the `uuidgen` executable is used: try it from the command line and see what it gives you. Edit your question and add that information to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you wedded to using `uuidgen`? Org-mode has its own internal functions to generate uuid's, which will be used if you customize `org-id-method` to `org`.  See <kbd>C-h v org-id-method RET</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, on MacOS write a `uuidgenlc` script that downcases the output of the "real" `uuidgen` and set

```el
(setq org-id-uuid-program "/path/to/uuidgenlc")
```

`uuidgenlc`  could be as simple as

```
#! /bin/bash

uuidgen | tr A-Z a-z
```